# eBay API GetOrders call for Half.com orders returns no results

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I definitely have orders that meet these constraints.  The credentials have been proven working.  Why isn't this call returning anything?  Note that when I remove

```
<ListingType>Half</ListingType>
```

then the call returns my eBay orders with no problem. Note that the eBay API spec does confirm that this call applies to Half.com orders.

```
HEADERS:
Content-Type: text/xml
X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: *****
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: GetOrders
X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: *****
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 805
X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: *****
X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0

REQUEST:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"> 
    <RequesterCredentials>   
        <eBayAuthToken>*****</eBayAuthToken> 
    </RequesterCredentials> 
    <Pagination>   
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>   
        <EntriesPerPage>100</EntriesPerPage> 
    </Pagination> 
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel> 
    <ListingType>Half</ListingType> 
    <NumberOfDays>30</NumberOfDays> 
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetOrdersRequest>

RESPONSE:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2013-02-13T01:58:24.294Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>807</Version>
    <Build>E807_CORE_BUNDLED_15702123_R1</Build>
    <PaginationResult>
        <TotalNumberOfPages>0</TotalNumberOfPages>
        <TotalNumberOfEntries>0</TotalNumberOfEntries>
    </PaginationResult>
    <HasMoreOrders>false</HasMoreOrders>
    <OrderArray/>
    <OrdersPerPage>100</OrdersPerPage>
    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
    <ReturnedOrderCountActual>0</ReturnedOrderCountActual>
</GetOrdersResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I ran into a similar issue and found the GetOrders API only works for half.com if you also specify the order status in the request.   Also only two order status values are valid for half.com.  Only specify one of them in each request.   Basically you have to get all orders with an "Active" request, then make a second pass and update those that have shipped in yet another request.

```
<OrderStatus>Active</OrderStatus>

<OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>
```